# nginx blank page with puma and rails on beanstalk

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to deploy rails api to elastic beanstalk with nginx and puma as the app server. THe deploy was successful, database created and migrated.

However, when accessing the web, it just show whitepage.

I can see that the request was recorded in nginx access log, however its not recorded in puma log.

Following is nginx conf :

```
> user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] 
"$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80 ;
    listen       [::]:80 ;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

The conf uses include directives, which has following content :
    upstream my_app {
      server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
    }

```
log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                '$http_x_forwarded_for';

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;
    set $hour $4;
  }

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /assets {
    alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /public {
    alias /var/app/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs file probably nginx is not configured correctly, if so you can refer to these posts for the solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360715/elastic-beanstalk-customize-puma-configuration)
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938155/right-way-to-deploy-rails-puma-postgres-app-to-elastic-beanstalk). Basically you need to ssh into your instance and customize the nginx configuration file stored at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, you need to bind there the puma server to a unix socket and it connects with NGINX. Example of the NGINX configuration file:

```
user  root;

error_log  /var/log/app-nginx-error.log;
pid        /var/run/app-nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  8096;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
    ....

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream appserver {
        server unix:///var/run/puma.sock;
    }

    .... 
}
```

The important part that you should add to the NGINX configuration file is:

```
upstream appserver {
  server unix:///var/run/puma.sock;
}
```